Re-ordering ACF Flexible Content Fields in Wordpress, not by order in PHP file?
Currently I have a single.php file where I am calling all my ACF fields, which are displaying all okay. The only issue is that they are displaying in the order they appear in the single.php rather than the order in my Wordpress Admin. Am I missing something really obvious here? Should these custom fields be added to a separate php file and called into the single.php file in particular way? It is worth noting that I am using Classic Editor as this is my preference.
I have researched about this and perhaps I am getting my terminology wrong I can't seem to find any related articles or questions that have been asked in the past.
<div id="main">
  <section>
     <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
     <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="project">
           <?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' ); ?>

              <div id="feature_image" style="background: url('<?php echo $backgroundImg[0]; ?>') no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>

              <div class="project_body">
                 
                 <div class="project_hero_text">
                    <ul>
                       <li>
                          <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                          <div class="services">
                             <h3><?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'service' ); 
                                            
                                   if($terms != null) {
                                   end($terms);
                                   $endKey = key($terms);
                                   foreach($terms as $key => $term) {
                                      echo $key != $endKey? $term->name.", " : $term->name;
                                      unset($term);
                                   }
                                   }?>
                             </h3>
                          </div>
                       </li>

                       <li>
                          <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                       </li>
                    </ul>
                 </div>

                 <div class="single_wide">
                    <?php if( have_rows('project_sections') ): ?>
                    <?php while( have_rows('project_sections') ): the_row(); ?>
                       <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'single_wide' ): 
                             $image = get_sub_field('image'); ?>
                             <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" alt="">
                       <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                 </div>

                 <div class="two_column_wide">
                    <?php if( have_rows('project_sections') ): ?>
                       <?php while( have_rows('project_sections') ): the_row(); ?>
                          <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'two_column_wide' ): 
                                $left = get_sub_field('left');
                                $right = get_sub_field('right'); ?>
                                <ul>
                                   <li>
                                      <img src="<?php echo $left['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $left['alt']; ?>" alt="">
                                   </li>

                                   <li>
                                      <img src="<?php echo $right['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $right['alt']; ?>" alt="">
                                   </li>
                                </ul>
                                
                          <?php endif; ?>
                       <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                 </div>

                 <div class="single_small">
                    <?php if( have_rows('project_sections') ): ?>
                       <?php while( have_rows('project_sections') ): the_row(); ?>
                          <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'single_small' ): 
                                $image = get_sub_field('image'); ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" alt="">
                          <?php endif; ?>
                       <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                 </div>

                 <div class="two_column_small">
                    <?php if( have_rows('project_sections') ): ?>
                       <?php while( have_rows('project_sections') ): the_row(); ?>
                          <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'two_column_small' ): 
                                $left = get_sub_field('left');
                                $right = get_sub_field('right'); ?>
                                <ul>
                                   <li>
                                      <img src="<?php echo $left['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $left['alt']; ?>" alt="">
                                   </li>

                                   <li>
                                      <img src="<?php echo $right['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $right['alt']; ?>" alt="">
                                   </li>
                                </ul>
                                
                          <?php endif; ?>
                       <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                 </div>


                 <div class="project_text">
                    <?php if( have_rows('project_sections') ): ?>
                    <?php while( have_rows('project_sections') ): the_row(); 
                       ?>
                       <?php if( get_row_layout() == 'project_text' ): ?>
                       <p>
                       <span class="annotation">
                          <?php echo str_replace('<br>', '\n', get_sub_field( 'annotation' )); ?>
                       </span>
                       <?php echo str_replace('<br>', '\n', get_sub_field( 'text' )); ?></p>
                       <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                 </div>

                 <div class="project_credits">
                 <?php if( have_rows('credits') ): ?>
                    <ul>
                    <?php while( have_rows('credits') ) : the_row();

                             // Get parent value.
                             $parent_title = get_sub_field('credit');

                             // Loop over sub repeater rows.
                             if( have_rows('credit') ):
                                   while( have_rows('credit') ) : the_row();

                                      // Get sub value.
                                      $child_title = get_sub_field('name'); ?>
                                      
                                         <li>
                                            <p>
                                            <span class="annotation">
                                               <?php echo str_replace('<br>', '\n', get_sub_field( 'discipline' )); ?>
                                            </span>
                                            <a href="<?php echo str_replace('<br>', '\n', get_sub_field( 'link' )); ?>">
                                               <?php echo str_replace('<br>', '\n', get_sub_field( 'name' )); ?>
                                            </a>
                                            </p>
                                            
                                         </li>
                                      

                                   <?php endwhile; ?>
                                   <?php endif; ?>
                             <?php endwhile; ?>
                          </ul>
                       <?php endif; ?>
                 </div>

                 

                 <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
                    
           </div>
        </div>

     <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?> 
    <?php endif; ?>
  </section>

</div>


How are you rendering these fields in PHP? With code such as get_field or the_field, or something else?

@ChrisHaas have_rows / get_row_layout / get_sub_field etc. and placing these inside html p / ul / li tags etc.

So when using the standard have_rows pattern for flexible content, each layout added should be in the order provided by the content person, is that not happening? For instance, you've got an FC with three possible layouts: "Staff", "Event", "News". A person adds two Event items followed by a Staff and a News. Are those items in the correct order? So only the_sub_field parts are not in the correct order?

Everything in the subfields is in the correct order and appear as per my ACF set up for each field within the flexible content. The problem is how they appear on my site when I reorder the post page order of content. For example, I am building a portfolio site and have different layouts such as 'Full Width' and '2 Column' if I change the order in the post admin page the order doesn't change on my site and remains in the order they have been listed in my single.php

show us the content of single.php

Have edited my original question. Please bear in mind I am very new to PHP so don't judge my code haha.
Also, I did wonder whether it is because I am calling 'project_sections' for each div, rather than nesting those div's inside of the first 'while' statement/

I have just changed this so that all div's are nested within the 'project_sections' if/while which now seems to be doing the trick but has thrown my css spacing completely out of whack.

Since fixed it... Sorry, I am new to PHP so getting to terms with how to structure. When I updated the structure I also moved each if statement for each type into the div, having now moved this outside of the div it is working. In other words the div is now nested inside each field 'get_row_layout if statement.
